# Rounded edges for recharts line chart

Tags: svg, linechart, recharts

I am trying to create a line chart with `linear` curve type but with rounded corners. Something like the following

[image]

However, putting in the `type` as `linear` creates crisp edges, like the following
[image]

How do I go about smoothening the edges and the joins of the line?

Code Snippet

```
<Line
  type='linear'
  dataKey='dataKey'
  stroke='#FFA500'
  strokeWidth={6}
  dot={false}
/>
```

Comment: Try `strokeLinejoin="round"`

Comment: thanks a lot @r3mainer. couldnt find this prop in the doc. used this along with `strokeLinecap` and it did the magic!

Answer (score 1):

You can use  `tension: 0.5` in your dataset.